# :after not working as expected

Tags: html, css

In the code below, I want to add a line after the div. I have used :after but the line comes before the div. Please help me on this.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 24px auto 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "but the line comes before the div"? What is the result you want?

Comment: Please check the code below. I have given div:after and added a blue line with div:after. I want the blue line to be after the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this using position

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

div:after { 
    content: "";
    background-color: blue;
    height: 2px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 24px auto 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The name `::after` for the pseudo-element can be a little misleading. It doesn't come after the *element* the selector is targeting, but *inside* it, *after* all the other content.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 24px auto 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

(and because your div has no content, it doesn't matter whether you use `::before` or `::after`).

So you either have to use positioning to move the blue line to be (visually) after the `div`, or you could apply your `::after` to the parent element of the div, which may or may not do what you want:

```css
#inner {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#outer:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 24px auto 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set line by using below code

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
      background-color: red;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;

    }
    div::after {
      content: " ";
      background-color: blue;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 2px;
      width: 120px;
      left: 100%;
    }

    </style>
    <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the  `margin-top` property of the `after` selector equal to your required div height,and add `float:left;`

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
   float:left;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 300px auto 0;
  display: block;
   
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```